# Scraping a HTML table with Rvest not working

Tags: html, rvest

I am trying to retrieve the table under the 'Results Table' tab at [this webpage](https://bccsu-drugsense.onrender.com/)
[image]

I'm encountering issues when trying to inspect the elements of this table.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

html_code <- read_html("https://bccsu-drugsense.onrender.com/")

html_code

## {html_document}
## <html>
## [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics --><script async src="https://www ...
## [2] <body>\n        \n<div id="react-entry-point">\n    <div class="_dash-loading">\n        Loading...\n    </div>\n</div>\n\n        <footer><script id="_dash-con ...
```

Usually this would return the HTML code, but for some reason it is not matching what I'm seeing on via devtools on the webpage itself. The only element returned in the `<body>` section is `<div class="_dash-loading">`. Therefore, when I try to inspect elements of the webpage it returns null.

```
html_code %>% html_elements("div") 
## {xml_nodeset (2)}
## [1] <div id="react-entry-point">\n    <div class="_dash-loading">\n        Loading...\n    </div>\n</div>
## [2] <div class="_dash-loading">\n        Loading...\n    </div>

html_code %>% html_elements("table") 
## {xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Not sure what `Loading...` means in this context, so would appreciate any advice and/or workaround. Thank you.

Comment: Could be that the table is not in the html, but rather is rendered via javascript upon an ajax result. The hint or clue is the "Loading..." you see in the code. Thats a placeholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of this page a rendered via javascript. `rvest::read_html()` can not capture this as it does not execute the javascript. The current development build of `rvest` has a new function for this: `read_html_live()`.

It uses the `chromote` package, which relies on Google Chrome being installed on your system.

To install the dev version of `rvest`:

```
remotes::install_github("tidyverse/rvest")
```

With little modifications to your code, you can get to the table. Instead of `read_html()` we use `read_html_live()`. We then use `html_code$click()` to emulate a click on the tab for the table. Finally, `rvest::html_table()` extracts tables from a HTML document and turns them into a `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


html_code <- read_html_live("https://bccsu-drugsense.onrender.com/")
html_code$click("li.nav-item:nth-child(3) > a:nth-child(1)")
html_table(html_code)
```

(Note: This works for me on Linux. On Windows `read_html_live()` is not working for me yet.)

Comment: I'm running a Windows machine so cannot test this. Appreciate the insight however - will look out for an updated version of rvest

Comment: I think it should work on windows, it just doesn't for me.